# Get the fetched values from the database

Tags: mysql, perl

I need to store the fetched data from the MySQL database. So I used this code.

```
while (@row = $statement->fetchrow_array) 
{
  print "@row.\n"; #        ------printing data
}

foreach $key(@row)
{
  print $key."\n"; # ------empty data
}
```

In foreach loop the @row data is empty. How to solve this

**UPDATE**: It actually should be like this:

```
while (my @row = $statement->fetchrow_array) { 
  # print "@row.\n";
  foreach my $key(@row) { 
    $query= "ALTER TABLE tablename DROP FOREIGN KEY $key;"; 
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query); 
    $statement->execute() 
      or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n"; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: What's that `$key` in the first loop? The obvious answer is that you need to use `foreach` _within_ `while` loop, but somehow I don't think that's all here.

Comment: I'm getting error like DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_array failed: fetch() without execute()

Comment: @StefanEdwards Can you provide full code? Code before while. What is in `$statement` before while?

Comment: @StefanEdwards Also you are using `ALTER TABLE` not `select` statement, so it won't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it *should* be like this:

```
while (my @row = $statement->fetchrow_array) {
  foreach my $key (@row) {
    print $key."\n";
  }
}
```

Otherwise all the result set will be consumed in the first loop.

As a sidenote, `fetchrow_array` returns a rowset as array of field *values*, not *keys*. To get the keys as well, you should use `fetchrow_hashref`:

```
while (my $row = $statement->fetchrow_hashref) {
  while (my ($key, $value) = each %$row) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** from your comments it looks like you actually need an array of column names. There's one way to do it:

```
my $row = $statement->fetchrow_hashref;
$statement->finish;
foreach my $key (keys %$row) {
  # ... dropping $key from db as in your original example
}
```

But in fact, there are more convenient ways of doing what you want to do. First, there's a single method for preparing and extracting a single row: `selectrow_hashref`. Second, if you want to get just foreign keys information, why don't use the specific DBI method for that - `foreign_key_info`? For example:

```
my $sth = $dbh->foreign_key_info( undef, undef, undef,
                                  undef, undef, $table_name);
my $rows = $sth->fetchall_hashref;
while (my ($k, $v) = each %$rows) {
  # process $k/$v
}
```

Comment: while ( my @row = $statement->fetchrow_array)
 { 
#print "@row.\n"  
 foreach my $key(@row)
 {
  $query= "ALTER TABLE tablename  DROP FOREIGN KEY $key;"; 
  
 $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
 

 $statement->execute()or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
  }
  }

Comment: can you please align it. i don't know hoe to do that

Comment: I need to drop the fetched keys in the database. If I use this code means it'll delete only first data and then for next data throws exception

Comment: I've moved your code into the question, please delete your comment. And I can't help wondering why you skipped it the first time; it's not welcomed making 'chameleon questions', that you just keep updating as you get answers, instead of separate ones.

Comment: I thought from the first question itself i got answer. but my bad time i didn't get any thing

Comment: Can you please give some sample code for selectrow_hashref and foreign_key_info

Comment: Updated my answer with example of how to use `foreign_key_info`, but, with all due respect, this is getting ridiculous.